# Python regex to match words not having dot

Tags: python, regex

I want to accept only those strings having the pattern 'wild.flower', 'pink.flower',...i.e any word preceding '.flower', but the word should not contain dot. For example, "pink.blue.flower" is unacceptable. Can anyone help how to do this in python using regex?

Comment: Is using regex a requirement, or did you just decide using it was easier?

Comment: It is a requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `"^\w+\.flower$"`.

Answer (score 1):

Is this sufficient?

```
^\w+\.\w+$
```

Comment: Accepts "pink.blue".

Comment: Oh I missed the fact that the second word needed to be flower :P My mistake, then yes `^\w\.flower$` is the requirement

Comment: @user2662833 you're close, you need a `+` after the `\w` :P

Answer (score 1):

To match any character except a newline or a dot you could use a negated [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[^.\r\n]+` and repeat that one or more times and use anchors to assert the start `^` and the end `$` of the line.

[`^[^.\r\n]+\.flower$`](https://regex101.com/r/bRghy6/1)

Or you could specify in a character class which characters you would allow to match followed by a dot `\.` and `flower`.

[`^[a-z0-9]+\.flower$`](https://regex101.com/r/bRghy6/2)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the regex for you. `^([^\.]*)\.flower$`.
Example: https://regex101.com/r/cSL445/1.

Comment: Accepts ".flower" (without anything in front of it).

Comment: @DyZ Go through the link and check out Match Information. It accepts word before `.flower` as the regex group.

Comment: Check for yourself: it accepts ".flower" (which is invalid, because there is nothing before the period).

Comment: @DyZ I am sorry, I haven't understood you. Check the link again. Here is the right one `^([^\.]+)\.flower`

Answer (score 0):

Your case of `pink.blue.flower` is unclear. There are 2 possibilities:

- Match only `blue` (cut off preceding dot and what was before).
- Reject this case altogether (you want to match a word preceding `.flower`
  **only** if it is not preceded with a dot).

In the first case accept other answers.

But if you want the **second** solution, use: `\b(?<!\.)[a-z]+(?=\.flower)`.

Description:

- `\b` - Start from a word boundary (but it allows the "after a dot" case).
- `(?<!\.)` - Negative lookbehind - exclude the "after a dot" case.
- `[a-z]+` - Match a sequence of letters.
- `(?=\.flower)` - Positive lookahead for `.flower`.

I assumed that you have only lower case letters, but if it is not the case,
then add `i` (case insensitive) option.

Another remark: Other answers include `\w`, which matches also digits and
`_` or even `[^\.]` - **any** char other than a dot (including e.g. `\n`).

Are you happy with that? If you aren't, change to `[a-z]` (again, maybe
with `i` option).