# REGEX match simple pattern

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match a simple pattern using `re` with `python` but I can't manage to reach a solution.

So I have to match a pattern like:

`word.word`

but **not** for example

`word.word.word`

My current REGEX is `[A-Za-z]+\.[A-Za-z]+` and matches both (**wrong**), I tried also with `^$` to include *start* and *end* of string but does not match any of them. I am doing something wrong, I really appreciate some help. Thanks

Comment: What code are you using to do the regex matching?

Comment: Doesn't `^[A-Za-z]+\.[A-Za-z]+$` really work? Show the code.

Comment: The anchors must work. Please edit the question to explain your issue if it still does not. Also, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50941395/3832970) to learn how to fail a match if there is a dot next to the match.

Answer (score 0):

```
re.match('^[A-Za-z]+\.[A-Za-z]+$', 'word.word') # return result
re.match('^[A-Za-z]+\.[A-Za-z]+$', 'word.word.word') # return None
```

Comment: Please explain your answer

Answer (score 0):

To match 2-words sequences (joined with `.` and containing only letters) within a text:

(also considering that a sequence could be followed with `.` pointing to the end of the sentence)

```
import re

test_str = 'some text word.word2.word3 with word.word and text with 1www.wewe11 and wordA.wordB.'
words = re.findall(r'(?<!\.)[a-z]+\.[a-z]+\b(?=[^\.]|\.?$)', test_str, re.I)

print(words)
```

The output:

```
['word.word', 'wordA.wordB']
```